# boot.ci() can't compute confidence intervals for F1 score

Tags: statistics-bootstrap

I am trying to compute confidence intervals for F1 score using the boot package in R. But it doesn't seem to work and I am not sure why.

```
library(MLmetrics)
fci<-function(data,indices,x,y){
   d<-data[indices,]
   r<-F1_Score(x,y)
   r
}
set.seed(12345)
bootout<-boot(data=test,
              x=test$jbz,
              y=test$`DR_ai+jd`,
              R=2000,
              statistic=fci
              )
boot.ci(bootout)
```

Error:

```
[1] "All values of t are equal to  0.996637873066777 \n Cannot calculate confidence intervals"
NULL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(MLmetrics)
library(boot)
set.seed(12345)
fci<-function(data,indices,x,y){
   d<-as.data.frame(data[indices,])
   r<-F1_Score(d[,1],d[,2],positive=1)
   r
}

bootout<-boot(data=test,
              x=test$jbz,
              y=test$`DR_ai+jd`,
              R=2000,
              statistic=fci
              )
boot.ci(bootout,type="basic")
F1_Score(y_true = test$jbz, y_pred = test$`DR_ai+jd`,positive="1")
```

this works well~~